# My web cam does not work on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, chromium, webcam

I'm trying to use my laptop's web camera on Chromium web-browser(Version 39.0.2171.65 Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit).

I already have installed flash player and FlashPaper too, but the problem is the same: **camera doesn't work!**

I think same problem have many users of Linux Ubuntu like me.

So I hope we can discuss about it...

P.S. When I was using windows os camera was working without any problem!

Comment: Please install cheese with `sudo apt-get install cheese` and run it. Does it work with that installed?

Comment: Perhaps Ubuntu doesn't have the drivers for your webcam. Can you update the question with the model, and give the output of lspci -nn?

Comment: don't you mean `lsusb`? alot of times the webcam is actually connected through an internal usb port

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you do use Cheese webcam application. sometimes the default webcam app doesn't works !
Otherwise your webcam might have any problems for sure ! Ubuntu never had such a trouble with handycam for me !
try using lot of other webcam applications from ubuntu software center !